# Unbound local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have some code that i followed using a youtube tutorial and it runs fine, a friend followed the same code and it is identical to mine. both using python ide VScode, tested on python 3.10 and 3.9. The indents are exactly the same in fact everything is the same as mine.

The code works perfectly on my computer but not my friends as she gets the 'unbound local variable referenced before assignment error' which i do not get.

Can anyone recommend why this might be happening?

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes


listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('Listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command

def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        print(song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
        print(time)
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'date' in command:
        talk('sorry, I have a headache')
    elif 'are you single' in command:
        talk('I am in a relationship with Siri')
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
        talk('Please say that again.')

while True:
    run_alexa()
```

Comment: In the *take_command* function, there is a potential problem. If an exception occurs during sr.Microphone() or listener.listen() or  listener.recognize_google() then *command* will not exist - but you try to return it

Answer (score 2):

Really, there should be more information with that error that pinpoints the actual problem.

However, I suspect the problem is this function:

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('Listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Obviously it expects that an exception might be thrown somewhere. If an exception is thrown by the line

```
voice = listener.listen(source)
```

Then the code will proceed until the line

```
return command
```

Without encountering a line where `command` is assigned anything.

What *should* the behaviour be if this function can't construct a command? Does it make sense to try and continue if you've failed to do a vital step in the process? It probably shouldn't be to try and return the command it failed to make :)

I'd suggest just removing the `try...except`:

```
def take_command():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        command = command.lower()
        if 'alexa' in command:
            command = command.replace('alexa', '')
            print(command)
    return command
```

It will still fail, but now at least you'll get an exception and a traceback that describes the actual problem.

Comment: Hi yes sorry I should have said but this is the location the error is focusing on that and the variable 'command' is the issue. but this code runs fine on my laptop. exactly like this. could it be something she is missing by installing vscode?

Comment: You're catching and ignoring an exception - that will tell you why it's not working... but also the code is incorrect if it fails this way anyway - if you just take out the `try...except` it will fail in a much more useful way

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't helping the problem, because the code works I do not get any errors and it works fine each time I run it. I just want to know why it works on my laptop but not on my friends when the code is identical, same ide and same version of python. It also runs like this on the YouTube tutorial we both copied it from. I'm wondering if there is an issue during installing python and vscode that is causing a problem on my friends laptop

Comment: You can't debug on your computer where it works to find out why it doesn't work on your friends computer - remove the try except on your friend's computer, and see what exception is actually being thrown - or at least log it in the except block or something.